# After shuffling the positions of an array traversing it becomes a lot slower, why is that?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have a big array with teams (1M). Each of those teams has 10 elements.
The pool of elements is stored in a map (id -> { id, points }).
If I calculate the points for each team it's pretty fast (as expected).
But if then I alter the array the calculation of the points performance decreases for around 5x.
Does someone has an idea what could be the issue? Here's the code if you want to have a look: https://playcode.io/656462/

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array for the first time, most of the memory is alloted consecutively.
Each element points towards the immediate next which is probably consecutively stored in memory. Once you shuffle the array, the values stay at the same addresses. Only the corresponding pointers change. So now your memory is not sequential. It's randomly spread.

Now when you try to traverse it, computer hardware takes more time to find those randomly spread memory locations than it would in a sequential memory. You wouldn't notice this with small arrays but this will be a factor when you're working on huge data like in your case.

*I didn't really find a source on the internet to back my answer, I would have commented this rather than answering but I don't have enough reputation. This answer is based on my understanding of CS*

Comment: That was my initial thought, but if it's in memory, shouldn't the access time to those pointers be the same regardless if they're sequential or not?

Comment: could be... it actually depends a lot on the type of memory. I don't wanna dive really deep into hardware cause that isn't my thing. I also don't have much idea about RAMs but taking an example of SSD vs HDD. HDD would take more time if it were to access random memory locations. SSD would be faster for accessing non sequential memory addresses.